# What are the major frameworks/libraries for Java AOP?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, aop, aspectj

I'm aware of AspectJ, Spring, and JBoss. Are there other mature and widely adopted frameworks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's popular dependency injection library [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP) can perform AOP on non-final injected instances.

Comment: Seems like Guice supports AOP through method interception. But does it also support annotation with attributes like `@NotOnDays({Days.SUNDAY, Days.SATURDAY})` as shown in this [example](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP#example-forbidding-method-calls-on-weekends)!

Answer (score 4):

I think all of them, AspectJ, SprintAOP and JBossAOP, are widely used. But they are different at some aspects. What you need to do is to choose the most proper one for your project.

For example, here is Spring AOP vs AspectJ
[Spring AOP vs AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606559/spring-aop-vs-aspectj)

Answer (score 3):

Depends upon what platform you are working upon but CDI, part of the Java EE 6 specification, has some pretty decent AOP features within it now.  Rick Hightower does an excellent job of walking through its capabilities in an article here:  http://cdisource.org/site/2011/05/cdi-aop-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

[AspectwerkZ](http://aspectwerkz.codehaus.org/introduction.html) is also widely used.[check it is merged with AspectJ](http://aspectwerkz.codehaus.org/introduction.html)

Comment: AspectWerkz was merged with AspectJ long ago: http://aspectwerkz.codehaus.org/index-merge.html