# Spring AOP or AspectJ or Spring with AspectJ

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj

Difference between Spring AOP, AspectJ and Spring AOP with Annotation?

Here is my understanding:

1. Spring AOP means Springs Aspect oriented programming with xml based configurations.
2. AspectJ means its another AOP implementation which is not spring based, if we want to use it then we need to include some third party jars apart from spring.
3. Spring AOP annotation means spring uses AspectJ annotations to provide AOP feature.

are these fair assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. Spring AOP have a limited options on AOP. The constructor and fields cant be intercepted with Spring AOP but it can be done using AspectJ.

Spring AOP also requires few AspectJ libries, like AspectJ weaving etc..

You can refer the link for more details.
[Spring AOP vs AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606559/spring-aop-vs-aspectj)