# LazyInitializationException from constructor injected @Repository in @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) method

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Use case:**

I'm building an importer for a CSV file, I have an `@Controller` to upload the CSV file and `@Entity`'s for the CSV file and the lines in the CSV file.
As the CSV files can get quite big I want to import them `@Async`.

**Problem**

When I upload a file, I save it to the database and trigger my async function to process it, this works. Then I process each line in an own transaction and save it as an Entity with its line number to the database, this also works fine. Then i trigger the actual business logic to process the line from the CSV line, which is *also* executed in its own transaction.

In this last transaction I get a `LazyInitializationException` from a repository that is used in that class and I don't know why.

In the catch block of the caller I use the exception message and save it to the database, this works as desired in its own transaction.
My upload page immediately returns, the CSV file is processed asynchronously, I get the error for every line in the CSV file, which are saved to the database.

Afterwards I have everything in the database as it should (not) be.

*Questions / Thoughts*

The repository seems to use another transaction, so it's not using the transaction from the `Importer` class, why?

This is what the final class looks like where the `LazyInitializationException` is thrown, calling classes are documented below.

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class Importer {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Importer(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    void import(String[] importLine) {
        getPersonAddress(importLine);
    }

    private PersonAddress getPerson(String[] importLine) {
        String name = importLine[5];
        Person person = personRepository.findByName(name);
        // This results in the following exception:
        // org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: de.twimbee.Person.addresses, could not initialize proxy - no Session
        return person.getAddresses().get(1);
    }
}
```

**Other Classes**

the controller used to upload the file and save it to the database.

```
@Controller
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class MyController {

    private final CsvFileRepository csvFileRepository;
    private final CsvImporter csvImporter;

    public MyController(CsvFileRepository csvFileRepository, CsvImporter csvImporter) {
        this.csvFileRepository = csvFileRepository;
        this.csvImporter = csvImporter;
    }

    public String postFile(String filename) {
        CsvFile csvFile = new CsvFile(filename)
        csvFile = csvFileRepository.save(new CsvFile(filename));

        try {
            List<String[]> csvContent = readCsvContent(filename);
            csvImporter.import(csvFile.getId(), csvContent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            csvFile.setError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The service that solely exists for spring to be able to intercept the @Async

```
@Service
public class CsvImporter {

    private final LineImporter lineImporter;

    public CsvImporter(LineImporter lineImporter) {
        this.lineImporter = lineImporter;
    }

    @Async
    void import(int csvFileId, List<String[]> csvContent) {
        for(int i = 0; i < csvContent.size(); i++) {
            lineImporter.import(csvFileId, csvContent.get(i), i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

the line importer with `REQUIRES_NEW` so that each line is imported in its own transaction.

```
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class LineImporter {

    private final CsvFileRepository csvFileRepository;
    private final ImportLineRepository importLineRepository;
    private final Importer importer;

    public LineImporter(CsvFileRepository csvFileRepository, ImportLineRepository importLineRepository, Importer importer) {
        this.csvFileRepository = csvFileRepository;
        this.importLineRepository = importLineRepository;
        this.importer = importer;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    void import(int csvFileId, String[] csvContent, int lineNumber) {
        ImportLine importLine = new ImportLine(lineNumber);
        importLine.setCsvFile(csvFileRepository.findOne(csvFileId));
        try {
            int dataId = importer.import(importLine);
            importLine.setDataId(dataId);
        } catch (ImportException e) {
            importLine.setError(e.getMessage());
        }
        importLineRepository.save(importLine);
    }
}
```

until this point everything seems to work as desired. The `Importer` throws an exception for every line, the error message get written to the database.

the repositories basically all look the same.

```
@Repository
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public interface CsvFileRepository extends JpaRepository<CsvFile, Integer> {
}
```

Comment: Can you post code for you address entity and person entity. It seems you have 
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)  instead of 
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) in your person entity wherever you are establishing relation between address and person

Comment: @user8271644 It is a @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY), you are correct that EAGER would help, but that is not what I want, I want the data to be lazily fetched in the same transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
void import(int csvFileId, String[] csvContent, int lineNumber) {
```

By default @Transactional works only on public methods

To change that u need to switch from Spring AOP Proxt to AspecJ Proxy

You can find more details here
[Spring AOP vs AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606559/spring-aop-vs-aspectj)

Comment: Damn, so easy to fix :D Thank you very much!